# reset auto increment to zero in mysql trigger when current year changed

Tags: mysql, triggers, increment

I need unique reference number combining year with auto increment field (like 17001.. here 17 is last two digit of 2017 and 001 is auto increment field) somehow i manage to create this combination using triggers but my problem is when new year starts auto increment should start from 001 again (like 18001 when 2018 starts)..

Thanks in advance

my table name is chalan and trigger table namem is chalan_seq

my code is:

```
    DELIMITER $$ 
    CREATE TRIGGER tg_chalan_insert
    BEFORE INSERT ON chalan 
    FOR EACH ROW 
    BEGIN 
    DECLARE curdate INT; 
    DECLARE lastdate INT; 
    SET curdate = DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%y'); 
    SET lastdate = (SELECT SUBSTR(ref,5,2) from chalan order by ref DESC LIMIT 1 
    ); 
    END 
    if(curdate != lastdate) 
    BEGIN
    DELETE FROM chalan_seq; 
    ALTER TABLE chalan_seq AUTO_INCREMENT = 0; 
    END$$  
    ELSE 
    BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO chalan_seq VALUES (NULL); 
    SET NEW.ref = CONCAT('GEMS',DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%y'), 
    LPAD(LAST_INSERT_ID(), 3, '0')); 
    END$$  
    DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Does your version of MySQL actually accept that?

Comment: You really need that? there is very small benefit on restart sequence to 0 every year,

Answer (score 0):

Just create a column with `AUTO_INCREMENT` and:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-using-sequences.htm

```
 ALTER TABLE chalan AUTO_INCREMENT = 2018000;
```

But this can create a problem if you insert more than 1000 records in one year.